# Buttons not on same level with float and PartialView

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, razor, css-float

I have following two Buttons at the end of my view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="Left"><input type="submit" value="Test" class="button"/></div>
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (Model.Test != null)
            {
                @Html.Partial("_BackButton", Model.Test)
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

_BackButton Partial View:

```
@model Test.Model.Shared.Test[]

@if (this.Model != null && this.Model.Length > 1)
{
    <div class="Right">
        <a href="@this.Model[this.Model.Length - 2].Url" class="button">@this.Model[this.Model.Length - 2].BackButtonLabel</a>
    </div>
}
```

And her the two classes in the css file:

```
div.Left {
    padding-right: 20px;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.Right {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

But unfortunately the two buttons are not on the same level:

[image]

Do I have a problem with the partial view here or is it the float attribute?
How can I work around this problem, so the buttons appear in the same line?

Comment: There are no margins involved?

Comment: There actually are (in the button class): margin: 15px 10px 15px 0px;

Comment: I'm afraid what you show on image is not explained for anything on question body. Use chrome developer tools to explore styles and see why it looks like that

Comment: Have you tried to inspect your code in web inspector in ie. chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `button` class does not contain `inline-block` or similar, the vertical margins defined in it will not work for inline elements like `<a>`. So the margins get applied only to the `<input>`.

Simplified example:

```css
table,
td {
  border: 1px solid;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.button {
  border: none;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #66F;
  margin: 15px 10px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="button" type="button" value="input">
    </td>
    <td>
      <a class="button" href="button">a</a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

So the solution is to remove the `margin` from the styles, or put `display:inline-block` in.